# Android - Show events by hour in calendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

I've been looking to make a calendar that will show events like the following picture below in android. Can this be done with CalendarView? What is the best way to go about this?

[image]

I hope this isn't a duplicate, i looked through stackoverflow for a similar answer but there was no good starting point for calendarViews. Thank you for looking.

Comment: What application is that on the Iphone?  It may help figure itout

Comment: honestly not too sure. I don't need that in particular. just looking for something that shows events by hour that i can plug events into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look around this [library](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)?

Comment: that seems like a great option. I'll look into it and reward if it shows to be a great option. Thanks for replying!

Comment: sorry for never commenting back. it worked great. thank you!

Comment: How to have month view with this library. ?